# Raspberry Pi 4B & ReSpeaker v2.0: PyAudio Errors and ALSA Configuration Issues

Tags: iot, pyaudio, raspberry-pi4, alsa, libalsa

OS: Raspberry Pi OS (64 bit) - Debian Bookworm

As a forewarning, I am a novice when it comes to IoT projects like this. My purpose is to implement my own custom python script which considers direction of arrival (DOA) and volume level of sound wrt DOA. The ReSpeaker v2.0 is a 4 mic array IoT board with an XMOS XVF-3000 processor that features 12 programmable RBG indicators. I want to have control over which LEDs turn on and what color they are wrt the DOA and intensity of sound. My referenced APIs are coming from ReSpeaker's usb_4_mic_array GitHub repo.

This is a simplified version of my script where get_volume_level() is giving me the most problems:

```
def map_direction_to_led(direction):...

def get_volume_level(chunk_size=512, format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=6, rate=16000, seconds=0.5, device_index=2):
    audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    stream = audio.open(format=format, channels=channels, rate=rate, input=True, frames_per_buffer=chunk_size, input_device_index=device_index) 
    frames = []
    for i in range(0, int(rate / chunk_size * seconds)):
        data = stream.read(chunk_size)
        frames.append(np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.int16))
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    audio.terminate()
    if frames:
        square_mean = np.mean(np.square(np.hstack(frames)))
        rms = np.sqrt(square_mean) if square_mean >= 0 else 0
        volume = np.log1p(rms) * 10 if not np.isnan(rms) else 0
    else:
        volume = 0
    return volume

volume_history = []
history_length = 3

def map_volume_to_color(volume_level):...

def light_up_led(pixel_ring, led_index, color):...

def main():...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

My primary problem is that PyAudio keeps throwing errors when trying to access ReSpeaker 4 Mic Array with specific configurations. These error messages continue to loop in the terminal when I compile my python script:

```
ALSA lib pcm_plug.c:933:(snd_pcm_plug_hw_refine_cchange) Slave format: IEC958_SUBFRAME_LE
ALSA lib pcm_plug.c:835:(snd_pcm_plug_hw_refine_schange) Unable to find an usable slave format for 'plug:hw'
ALSA lib pcm_plug.c:839:(snd_pcm_plug_hw_refine_schange) Format: S8
ALSA lib pcm_plug.c:839:(snd_pcm_plug_hw_refine_schange) Format: U8
ALSA lib pcm_plug.c:839:(snd_pcm_plug_hw_refine_schange) Format: S16_LE
ALSA lib pcm_plug.c:839:(snd_pcm_plug_hw_refine_schange) Format: S16_BE
ALSA lib pcm_plug.c:839:(snd_pcm_plug_hw_refine_schange) Format: U16_LE
ALSA lib pcm_plug.c:839:(snd_pcm_plug_hw_refine_schange) Format: U16_BE
ALSA lib pcm_plug.c:839:(snd_pcm_plug_hw_refine_schange) Format: S24_LE
ALSA lib pcm_plug.c:839:(snd_pcm_plug_hw_refine_schange) Format: S24_BE
ALSA lib pcm_plug.c:839:(snd_pcm_plug_hw_refine_schange) Format: U24_LE
ALSA lib pcm_plug.c:839:(snd_pcm_plug_hw_refine_schange) Format: U24_BE
ALSA lib pcm_plug.c:839:(snd_pcm_plug_hw_refine_schange) Format: S32_LE
ALSA lib pcm_plug.c:839:(snd_pcm_plug_hw_refine_schange) Format: S32_BE
ALSA lib pcm_plug.c:839:(snd_pcm_plug_hw_refine_schange) Format: U32_LE
ALSA lib pcm_plug.c:839:(snd_pcm_plug_hw_refine_schange) Format: U32_BE
ALSA lib pcm_plug.c:839:(snd_pcm_plug_hw_refine_schange) Format: S20_LE
ALSA lib pcm_plug.c:839:(snd_pcm_plug_hw_refine_schange) Format: S20_BE
ALSA lib pcm_plug.c:839:(snd_pcm_plug_hw_refine_schange) Format: U20_LE
ALSA lib pcm_plug.c:839:(snd_pcm_plug_hw_refine_schange) Format: U20_BE
ALSA lib pcm_plug.c:839:(snd_pcm_plug_hw_refine_schange) Format: S24_3LE
ALSA lib pcm_plug.c:839:(snd_pcm_plug_hw_refine_schange) Format: S24_3BE
ALSA lib pcm_plug.c:839:(snd_pcm_plug_hw_refine_schange) Format: U24_3LE
ALSA lib pcm_plug.c:839:(snd_pcm_plug_hw_refine_schange) Format: U24_3BE
ALSA lib pcm_plug.c:839:(snd_pcm_plug_hw_refine_schange) Format: S20_3LE
ALSA lib pcm_plug.c:839:(snd_pcm_plug_hw_refine_schange) Format: S20_3BE
ALSA lib pcm_plug.c:839:(snd_pcm_plug_hw_refine_schange) Format: U20_3LE
ALSA lib pcm_plug.c:839:(snd_pcm_plug_hw_refine_schange) Format: U20_3BE
ALSA lib pcm_plug.c:839:(snd_pcm_plug_hw_refine_schange) Format: S18_3LE
ALSA lib pcm_plug.c:839:(snd_pcm_plug_hw_refine_schange) Format: S18_3BE
ALSA lib pcm_plug.c:839:(snd_pcm_plug_hw_refine_schange) Format: U18_3LE
ALSA lib pcm_plug.c:839:(snd_pcm_plug_hw_refine_schange) Format: U18_3BE
```

Moreover, my print() statements in my script don't output anything to the terminal - all I see is the output above being looped continuously. Although this is sort of working on my end, I would prefer to have things run more efficiently. To clarify, these ALSA errors are not preventing the script from running, but they appear as warnings while the script still functions.

I've noticed I get the same output with or without ~/.asoundrc and /etc/asound.conf files, but here is what I have saved in both files at the moment:

```
pcm.!default {
    type asym
    capture.pcm "array"
}

pcm.array {
    type hw
    card 3
    device 0
}
```

Running arecord -l I get:

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 3: ArrayUAC10 [ReSpeaker 4 Mic Array (UAC1.0)], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Running this script below,

```
import pyaudio

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

print("Number of audio devices:", p.get_device_count())
for i in range(p.get_device_count()):
    dev = p.get_device_info_by_index(i)
    print("Device index:", i)
    print("Device name:", dev.get('name'))
    print("Input channels:", dev.get('maxInputChannels'))
    print("Output channels:", dev.get('maxOutputChannels'))
    print("Default Sample Rate:", dev.get('defaultSampleRate'))
    print("---------------------------------------")

p.terminate()
```

I get:

```
ALSA lib pcm_plug.c:933:(snd_pcm_plug_hw_refine_cchange) Slave format: IEC958_SUBFRAME_LE
ALSA lib pcm_plug.c:835:(snd_pcm_plug_hw_refine_schange) Unable to find an usable slave format for 'plug:hw'
ALSA lib pcm_plug.c:839:(snd_pcm_plug_hw_refine_schange) Format: S16_LE
ALSA lib pcm_plug.c:844:(snd_pcm_plug_hw_refine_schange) Slave format: IEC958_SUBFRAME_LE
ALSA lib pcm_plug.c:924:(snd_pcm_plug_hw_refine_cchange) Unable to find an usable client format
ALSA lib pcm_plug.c:928:(snd_pcm_plug_hw_refine_cchange) Format: S16_LE
ALSA lib pcm_plug.c:933:(snd_pcm_plug_hw_refine_cchange) Slave format: IEC958_SUBFRAME_LE
ALSA lib confmisc.c:160:(snd_config_get_card) Invalid field card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:482:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid card 'card'
ALSA lib confmisc.c:160:(snd_config_get_card) Invalid field card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:482:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid card 'card'
ALSA lib pcm_direct.c:1258:(snd1_pcm_direct_initialize_slave) requested or auto-format is not available
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1011:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to initialize slave
connect(2) call to /dev/shm/jack-1000/default/jack_0 failed (err=No such file or directory)
attempt to connect to server failed
Number of audio devices: 8
Device index: 0
Device name: vc4-hdmi-0: MAI PCM i2s-hifi-0 (hw:0,0)
Input channels: 0
Output channels: 2
Default Sample Rate: 44100.0
---------------------------------------
Device index: 1
Device name: bcm2835 Headphones: - (hw:2,0)
Input channels: 0
Output channels: 8
Default Sample Rate: 44100.0
---------------------------------------
Device index: 2
Device name: ReSpeaker 4 Mic Array (UAC1.0): USB Audio (hw:3,0)
Input channels: 6
Output channels: 2
Default Sample Rate: 16000.0
---------------------------------------
Device index: 3
Device name: sysdefault
Input channels: 0
Output channels: 128
Default Sample Rate: 44100.0
---------------------------------------
Device index: 4
Device name: hdmi
Input channels: 0
Output channels: 2
Default Sample Rate: 44100.0
---------------------------------------
Device index: 5
Device name: pulse
Input channels: 32
Output channels: 32
Default Sample Rate: 44100.0
---------------------------------------
Device index: 6
Device name: array
Input channels: 6
Output channels: 2
Default Sample Rate: 16000.0
---------------------------------------
Device index: 7
Device name: default
Input channels: 32
Output channels: 32
Default Sample Rate: 44100.0
---------------------------------------
```

following more of the same error messages getting thrown by PyAudio.

- Has anyone experienced similar issues with the Respeaker v2.0 on Raspberry Pi?
- Are there known compatibility issues with the current setup?
- Suggestions for alternative configurations or debugging steps?

Thank you for checking this out and I'd really appreciate any help or feedback. I am open to any suggestions, whether they pertain to my current approach or a completely different method.